# Wordpress: How to make a backup of a production production website to a local server like xampp

Tags: wordpress, backup

I want to make a backup of my production website to my local server xampp on my desktop. I try with Akeeba Backup but It's don't work correctly I have some errors during the proceed.

Do you have some tips for me ?

Best regard,
Lordaker.

Answer (score 0):

"BackupBuddy" or "updraftplus" are the best plugin to take backup and restore. Also In the BackupBuddy, you can set schedule backup.

Answer (score 0):

I've already try updraftplus but I can restore my backup to a local server because he ask me to buy an another extension. Do you known an another free extension to make backup and restoration to a wordpress website.

With Akeeba Backup, I can make a restoration of my website. But I have an issue with my website, I can't personalize them. And I don't understand why ?

Do you known, what's happen ?

Lordaker

Answer (score 0):

To make backup and restoration to a WordPress website BackupBuddy is good according to me, As it will create a separate backup file and you can restore it to local or live.

Answer (score 0):

But "BackupBuddy" or "updraftplus" are two not free. I must to buy it. That why I use Akeeba Backup. And actually my website is on a demo live version on an another hosting web server. If I make an install of one of this extensions (BackupBuddy or updraftplus) I will buy two time. One for for the demo website and one again for the production website.

is there an another free extension backup and restoration for cms WordPress ?

Regards,
Lordaker